# Event 17058 - initerrlog: Could not open error log file (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL Server and encountering an error when running `sqlservr.exe`
(Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2 - Express Edition)

> Error 17058, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''.
>   Operating System Error = 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.).

Here are my startup parameters:

```
-dc:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf;
-ec:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG;
-lc:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
```

I've also made sure that all users have full control access and removed read-only permission from folders

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem after windows update on our server. Resolved with these steps.

- rename or delete ERRORLOG file found in below directory

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log`

- start service

I think the file corrupted. When I change the name, it created a new file.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this EXACT issue two weeks ago. The resolution I found myself was that when you goto CMD prompt do not just open it, right click and say RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR. Then start SQL Server as you state. It will work that way. Security on WIn2008 is tighter and you have to do the RUN AS ADMIN for it to work correctly.

Comment: SQL Server runs as a service, not as an application, so there is no need normally to run it as Administrator, as the install performs the required permission grants. Security in Windows Server 2008 is not tighter than in Windows Server 2012 or 2016:  it has evolved in the right way, because the Security has evolved as well, and quite much, since 9 years ...